# Is there a way to generate an OpenApi Spec from a Spring App without having to run the Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I can run `./gradlew generateOpenApiDocs` to generate an OpenApi spec using the `springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin`. This however starts the Spring Boot application in the background using a forkedSpringBootRun task.

I was wondering if there was:

1. A way to generate the spec without running the Spring Boot Application and if that doesn't work
2. Make it so that the command runs every time the Spring Boot Application is run without having to run the command itself
3. Maybe add the command as part of an integration test that runs when the Spring Boot Application runs and generates the spec that way

Note: I am using this plugin because my app uses Spring WebFlux. I am open to other plugin suggestions that could generate docs without running the app if you have any.

Comment: No, that is the way the Gradle plugin is designed to work. It starts your Spring Boot application in order for [springdoc's](https://springdoc.org/) Spring auto-configuration to take effect. Underneath, it just makes a HTTP request to the configured `/v3/api-docs` URL for the specification file then just writes it to a file as the task output.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe add the command to an integration test to run it while the Spring Boot Application is running?